# Bash scripting: filling up an Array inside a for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I try to create an array that is filled up with some values. But i don't know how to do it. I tried something below but it didn't work.

**My code:**

```
i=0
for c in colors; do
array[$i]=$c
echo {$c[$i]}
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

**note:** "colors" is some kind of "ps -ef" command that returns a list of values. it has "blue,red,yellow" values for example.

```
colors= 'ps -ef | grep colors'
```

Comment: Exactly *how* the `colors` list is returned is important. If they're returned one-to-a-line, there are more reliable ways to get them out than string-splitting (which is what you're doing, and which is what your accepted answer does, which will change, for instance, a color `*` to a list of files in the current directory, or a color `light magenta` to two entries, `light` and `magenta`).

Comment: By the way, in bash, `(( ++i ))` is the modern way to write `i=$(expr $i + 1)`.

Comment: ...and the only thing completely nonfunctional with your code (as opposed to best-practices violations) was writing `{$c[$i]}` rather than `${c[$i]}` and `in colors` rather than `in $colors`.

Comment: ...also, as http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement documents, you should prefer the `pgrep` command rather than grepping the output of `ps`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this script to fill up the array in a loop:

```
array=()
for c in $colors; do
    array+=( "$c" )
done
```

OR even simpler:

```
array=( $(command) )
```

Comment: If we assume that string-splitting is a given, yes. The best-practices approach if the input is coming in one-to-a-line would be to use a while/read loop to split out the elements -- that way we don't have glob expansion, IFS-based splitting, or other such side effects.

Comment: is there a example about your "simpler" command? is it like "array=($("ps -ef|grep pmon"))"?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark, no quotes; just `array=( $(ps -ef | grep ...) )` -- but it's a bad practice for several reasons.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark: When you use `array=( $(command) )` then each element is delimited by space or new lines. So if your element itself contains spaces then that will be broken into multiple array elements. There are ways to handle this; e.g. using `IFS` appropriately as in Charles's answer.

Answer (score 5):

If your colors are coming in one-to-a-line, you're potentially losing information (dropping the distinction between spaces and newlines, expanding glob characters, etc) as soon as you expand the variable that stores them unquoted.

Don't do that. Instead, follow [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
colors=()
while IFS='' read -r color; do
    colors+=( "$color" )
done < <(get-color-list)
```

That's even more true if you only want, say, a specific column out of each line; `read` will do the column-splitting for you, making it easier to assign.